# delay between runs in bash on cluster

Tags: bash, delay, delayed-execution

I have to submit a large number of jobs on a cluster, I have a script like:

```
#!/bin/bash

for runname in bcc BNU Can CNRM GFDLG GFDLM
do
  cd given_directory/$runname
  cat another_directory | while read LINE ; do
    qsub $LINE
  done
done
```

There are 4000 lines in the script, i.e. 4000 jobs for each `runename`.

The number of jobs that can be submitted on the cluster is limited by a user at a given time.

So, I want to delay the process between each runs, in a given `for-loop` till
one batch, like all runs in `bcc` directory is done.

How can I do that? Is there a command that I can put after the first `done` (?) to  make the code to wait till `bcc` is done and then move to `BNU`?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use a counter to monitor how many jobs are currently submitted, and wait when the limit is reached. Querying the number of jobs can be a costly operation to the head node so it is better not to do it after every submitted job. Here, it is done maximum once every `SLEEP` seconds.

```
#!/bin/bash

TARGET=4000
SLEEP=300

# Count the current jobs, pending or running
get_job_count(){
  # The grep is to remove the header, there may be a better way.
  qstat -u $USER | grep $USER | wc -l
}

# Wait until the number of job is under the limit, then submit.
submit_when_possible(){
  while [ $COUNTER -ge $TARGET ]; do
    sleep $SLEEP
    COUNTER=$(get_job_count)
  done
  qsub $1
  let "COUNTER++"
}

# Global job counter
COUNTER=$(get_job_count)

for RUNNAME in bcc BNU Can CNRM GFDLG GFDLM
do
  cd given_directory/$RUNNAME
  cat another_directory | while read JOB ; do
    submit_when_possible $JOB
  done
done
```

Note: the script is untested, so it may need minor fixes, but the idea should work.